# Copy and paste after the last row VBA issue

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with my code. It does the trick of copy/paste correctly. However, I think there is something tricky. When I try to update my dynamic table it displays a message that the WB I'm currently working in already has data and if I want to replace it. When I choose "Yes/No" it immediately displays another column in my table that says that `81 registers are not been used in UTILITY`. When I do everything by hand there are no problems. So, I guess there´s something wrong with my macro.

```
Option Explicit

Sub DailyTrans_MDM()

    Call CopyPaste
End Sub

Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim vFile As Variant
    Dim folderPath As String
    Dim wbCopyTo As Workbook
    Dim wsCopyTo As Worksheet
    Dim wbCopyFrom  As Workbook
    Dim wsCopyFrom As Worksheet

    vFile = Dir(folderPath & "*.xl*")
    Set wbCopyTo = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsCopyTo = ActiveSheet
        Do While vFile <> ""        
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False    
            vFile = Application.GetOpenFilename("Daily Reports (*.xl*)," & "*.xl*", 1, "Select Report", "Open File", False)
            If TypeName(vFile) = "Boolean" Then
                Exit Sub
            Else
                Set wbCopyFrom = Workbooks.Open(vFile)
                Set wsCopyFrom = wbCopyFrom.Worksheets("ReporteCifrasControl")
            End If
    '--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            wsCopyFrom.Range("A2:M" & wsCopyFrom.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row).Copy
            wsCopyTo.Range("A" & wsCopyTo.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
            wbCopyFrom.Close SaveChanges:=False

            Dim rngCopy As Range, rngPaste As Range
                With ActiveSheet
                    Set rngCopy = .Range(.Range("A2"), Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
                    Set rngPaste = .Range(.Range("A2"), .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(, rngCopy.Columns.Count)
                End With
            rngCopy.Copy
            rngPaste.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Your paste range can just be one cell. No need to resize the paste range to match the copy range. Simplifying that may help you find your error. It also looks like you are just copying one row. Now sure if that is intentional

Comment: @urdearboy in the Sub Status i'm just copying one row into another row & what i intend to do with the resize is to give the data copied the same format as the one in the sheet, if i don't put the resize it pastes like the format of the other workbook.

Comment: You are copying a column range here, not just one row. Why is there so much code if the issue is with `Sub Status ()`? Seems like majority of this does not need to be read by us. Please [edit] your question to **only** show us the relevant code that you need help with. If you have multiple questions, then each question should get it's own post.

Comment: Already edited @urdearboy the problem is not with status, it's the copyPaste macro, don't know how to fix it though, that's why i'm asking for help.

Comment: @urdearboy yes, by selecting one row, for example the last one available and pasting the format into the new data i just copied, i give the whole pasted data the format of the rest of the data

Comment: The rngPaste should be the new pasted data, but i don't know how to refere to that, so i thought that i could just select all and it wouldn't affect the data but i guess it did because of the dynamic table, and even if i remove from Dim rng downwards, i still get the same problem.

Comment: @urdearboy OMW, i was gonna use the first one, gimme a minute

Comment: @urdearboy i have a doubt, i just ran the whole macro and had to repeat it again so i could change something, i ran it again and it doesn't do anything.

Comment: @urdearboy it's cleaner the code you gave me but i still have the same error, i can't figure out what's wrong with this.

Comment: Is it the format paste or the values paste that is giving you the issue. **elaborate on the error**. Saying it doesn't work tells us nothing and will not help to resolve.

Comment: Yeah, but why when i do it manually, the problem don't appear, i mean is just CTRL+C 6 CTRL +V and that's it, something so simple is giving me a pain, i'm too frustrated to keep digging on this

Comment: It's the format paste i think, because the values don't have to do nothing with that, what's curious is when it's done pasting the new data, the whole cells of the worksheet are selected, don't know why, i think maybe that is the root of the problem @urdearboy

Comment: I would just step through the code line by line using `F8` until you can spot exactly where the issue is. Sorry I couldn't help more.

Comment: Thank you @urdearboy i'll review it today and will send you a message.

Comment: @urdearboy made a way more clean version of the copy pasting, doesn't include the resize and i found the issue but i don't know why it affects when i update the dynamic table, when i do it manually it completely ignores them, can i make a macro to ignore those values ?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you want to do this

- Copy row 2 from `Column A to Last Used Column (LC)`
- Paste this in the first `Non-Used Row (LR)` in `Column A`

---

```
Dim LC As Long
Dim LR As Long

With ActiveSheet
    LC = .Cells(2, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    Set rngCopy = .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(LC, 2))
    Set rngPaste = .Range("A" & LR)
End With

rngCopy.Copy
rngPaste.PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
```

---

*You missed some objects to be qualified in your code. No point in using the `With Block` if you are not going to **use** the `With Block`*

---

Just realized you have multiple copy/pastes in your code. If this is the wrong one, use the format here to modify the other one.